# PHP/MySQL - where column IS NOT 0/NULL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run this SQL:

```
$sql="SELECT LEAST(".implode(',',$column_list).") as num FROM callplandata WHERE num IS NOT 0 ";
```

ERROR: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0' at line 1`

i have also tried

```
$sql="SELECT LEAST(".implode(',',$column_list).") as num FROM callplandata WHERE num IS NOT NULL ";
```

ERROR: `Unknown column 'num' in 'where clause'`

but i am getting the above errors for each one.

how can i get round this - i am trying to show the values that are NOT 0

Comment: Did you tried this - WHERE num != 0

Comment: yep and the same again - Unknown column 'num' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE` in this case.

```
$sql="SELECT LEAST(".implode(',',$column_list).") as num FROM callplandata HAVING num != 0 ";
```

What's the diffrence? `WHERE` is applied before `GROUP BY` operations, `LEAST` also have to group your results before return it (so WHERE clause is called before your results has been counted), `HAVING` is applied after (and can filter on aggregates such as `MIN, MAX, LEAST` etc).